# Using Orca.exe I need to create MST file on Client Side via Command Prompt

Tags: windows-installer, webdeploy, orca

While deploying my application's ClientSetup.msi I need to pass the Server IP address as a parameter. I have been advised to use Orca.exe to create MST file.
I need command line to do this as it needs to be automated from my Application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating an MST is extremely overkill for just passing a parameter to the install. It sounds like what you actually want is a public Property. Those get passed on the command line like:

```
msiexec /i path\to\your.msi YOURSERVERIP=0.0.0.0
```

Then put `[YOURSERVERIP]` in the right place in your MSI. I have a [video about doing just this using the WiX Toolset](https://www.youtube.com/live/cLIg7nxx1ko).

Comment: Passing a parameter each time can be error prone with typos. I want to give my user a single file Setup module.

Comment: I don't understand. If you create a custom MST per customer, you'll still have to pass the MST path on the command line using the `TRANSFORMS` parameter. It sounds like you want to build a custom installation package for each user.

Comment: You have put it appropriately, that I want to build a custom installation package for each user. I know it sounds weird. I did not know that I have to use the MST path on command line, then it defeats the purpose. Will need to drop this idea. JFYI currently I am building custom setup for each customer via InnoSetup, issue is that I cannot code sign that with my EV.

Comment: Yep, this is a fundamental issue with your requirements. It doesn't matter which installation technology you use. Well, you _could_ try to smuggle data in an unsigned portion of the executable (non-trivial, but I believe it is possible), but then that unsigned data is a target for tampering. Without knowing anything about your application, I'd recommend a different approach to your configuration problem that (ideally) does not require custom installation packages per-customer.

Comment: Will stick to your first recommendation. Thanks !! you have been extremely helpful.

Comment: This is what we do at FireGiant. Sometimes we do "charity cases". ;)